# How the order of multi providers works in angular4?

Tags: angular

In my existing angular4 application, app.module.ts, I had following APP_INITIALIZER  providers:

```
{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: (config: AntiforgeryService) => () => config.Load(),
    deps: [AntiforgeryService, GlobalService],
    multi: true
},

{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: RebarInterceptor,
    multi: true
},
{
    provide: ErrorHandler,
    useClass: GlobalExceptionHandler
}
```

After that, I got one requirement that I have to pass some token with my all HTTP calls. So that, I have to call the load method of AntiforgeryService first. So I decided to put  this load as providers like below:

```
{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: (config: AppConfig) => () => config.load(),
    deps: [AppConfig],
    multi: true
},      
{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: (config: AntiforgeryService) => () => config.Load(),
    deps: [AntiforgeryService, GlobalService],
    multi: true
},
{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: RebarInterceptor,
    multi: true
},
{
    provide: ErrorHandler,
    useClass: GlobalExceptionHandler
}
```

After putting this, I am getting some error in console:
*Some error occurred. Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'eso' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'eso' of null*

I have one config.json file, where I have this 'eso' property, which I am loading using the above providers (AppConfig).

Can anybody suggest that, is there any order issue in the provider section as I have mentioned above? Or is there any issue of multi-flag?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your `AntiforgeryService` uses the eso property from the `AppConfig`. The `APP_INITILAIZER` methods are run concurrently. My suggestion is to make one big initializer:

```
{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: loadConfigs,
    deps: [AppConfig, AntiforgeryService],
    multi: true
},
```

And created an exported function like this: (exported otherwise AOT doesn't work)

```
export const loadConfigs = (app: AppConfig, af: AntiforgeryService) => {
  return app.load().then(() => af.load());
};
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But we are using ES5, and I can see that aync await will be work with ES6 only or higher version. Correct me? With ES5 I have tried your suggestion but it's not working as expected.

Comment: @DilipSolanki I've updated my answer without async, but typescript should be able to handle it though, but hey, that's another question :)